# Spring security 4. Architect structure for user management page

Tags: json, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Spring Security uses **[UserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/UserDetailsManager.html)** to manage users & authorities.
I want use same implementation **[JdbcUserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html)** to manage user page by admin (user CRUD, managing groups, pagination). But unfortunately there is no implementation for paging, manage groups and so on.

**So I've got an issues:**

1. User CRUD because of json convertation for REST.
2. Group CRUD because of json convertation for REST.
3. User paging because of [UserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/UserDetailsManager.html) has no correspond implementation.
4. Group paging - no implementation.
5. User JSON to POJO (for create\update operations could be used *[UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html)* has implementations *[InetOrgPerson](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/InetOrgPerson.html)*, *[Person](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/Person.html)*, *[User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)* but... i've got json convertation issue, can not mark classes with *[@JsonIgnore](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html)*).
6. User POJO to JSON (for read operation i can not remove from data any important fields (for example: password)).

---

**All of this issues have few solution ways:**

1. **1.1.** Create one more user object similar to *[User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)*, add expected JSON annotations **OR** in rest controller create builder to build *[User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)* object from input parameter map (builder is good pattern by i think this is ugly way to manage something if it was implemented once)
   **1.2.** add spring-datajpa repository (duplicates some security part of *[JdbcUserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html)*) **OR** extend from *[JdbcUserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html)* and add unimplemented part to manage users, groups...
2. Solution is the same with 1.
3. If 1. implemeted using spring-data-jpa - no problems, other case it needs to implement correspond factory builders to provide paging in dynamic way.
4. Solution is the same with 3.
5. Solved on 1., 2. steps.
6. Solved on 1., 2. steps.

**Which solution way i should follow** (implement managers spring-data-jpa based with additional POJOs or expand functionality for [JdbcUserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html)) **?**

Describing situation, i think i'll implement solution using spring-data-jpa and extra POJO-entities to have all CRUD and JSON manipulating abilities. This way seems better saving implementation time, and code will be more cleaner for support generation.

If i mistook in my choice, let me know please. also please let me know if my issues already solved in spring (sorry i did not find solutions for described issues). Also i believe someone wants other solution architecture - i would discuss or consider clever ideas.